# How to mock Athena query results values with Moto3 for a specific table?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pytest, boto3, moto

I am using `pytest` and `moto3` to test some code similar to this:

```
response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString='SELECT * FROM xyz',
        QueryExecutionContext={'Database': myDb},
        ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': someLocation},
        WorkGroup=myWG
    )

execution_id = response['QueryExecutionId']

if response['QueryExecution']['Status']['State'] == 'SUCCEEDED':
    response = athena_client.get_query_results(
        QueryExecutionId=execution_id
    )

    results = response['ResultSet']['Rows']
    ...etc
```

In my test I need that the values from `results = response['ResultSet']['Rows']` are controlled by the test. I am using some code like this:

```
backend = athena_backends[DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID]["us-east-1"]
    rows = [{"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "xyz"}]}, {"Data": [{"VarCharValue": ...}, etc]}]
    column_info = [
        {
            "CatalogName": "string",
            "SchemaName": "string",
            "TableName": "xyz",
            "Name": "string",
            "Label": "string",
            "Type": "string",
            "Precision": 123,
            "Scale": 123,
            "Nullable": "NOT_NULL",
            "CaseSensitive": True,
        }
    ]
    results = QueryResults(rows=rows, column_info=column_info)
    backend.query_results[NEEDED_QUERY_EXECUTION_ID] = results
```

but that is not working as I guess `NEEDED_QUERY_EXECUTION_ID` is not known before from the test. How can I control it?

*UPDATE*

Based on suggestion I tried to use:

```
results = QueryResults(rows=rows, column_info=column_info)
d = defaultdict(lambda: results.to_dict())
backend.query_results = d
```

to force a return of values, but it seems not working as from the `moto3`'s `models.AthenaBackend.get_query_results`, I have this code:

```
    results = (
        self.query_results[exec_id]
        if exec_id in self.query_results
        else QueryResults(rows=[], column_info=[])
    )
    return results
```

which will fail as the `if` condition won't be satifsfied.

Comment: You could overwrite `backend.query_results` to be a `defaultdict`? That way it can always return your custom result, regardless of the value of `NEEDED_QUERY_EXECUTION_ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the solution of the `defaultdict`, you could create a custom dictionary that contains all `execution_ids`, and always returns the same object:

```
class QueryDict(dict):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True
     def __getitem__(self, item):
        rows = [{"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "xyz"}]}, {"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "..."}]}]
        column_info = [
            {
                "CatalogName": "string",
                "SchemaName": "string",
                "TableName": "xyz",
                "Name": "string",
                "Label": "string",
                "Type": "string",
                "Precision": 123,
                "Scale": 123,
                "Nullable": "NOT_NULL",
                "CaseSensitive": True,
            }
        ]
        return QueryResults(rows=rows, column_info=column_info)

backend = athena_backends[DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID]["us-east-1"]

backend.query_results = QueryDict()
```

Comment: Thank you for both the answers! I picked this one as works better for my test case but I will definitively consider the other one too for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to using custom dictionaries would to be seed Moto.

Seeding Moto ensures that it will always generate the same 'random' identifiers, which means you always know what the value of `NEEDED_QUERY_EXECUTION_ID` is going to be.

```
backend = athena_backends[DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID]["us-east-1"]
rows = [{"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "xyz"}]}, {"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "..."}]}]
column_info = [...]
results = QueryResults(rows=rows, column_info=column_info)
backend.query_results["bdd640fb-0667-4ad1-9c80-317fa3b1799d"] = results

import requests
requests.post("http://motoapi.amazonaws.com/moto-api/seed?a=42")

# Test - the execution id will always be the same because we just seeded Moto

execution_id = athena_client.start_query_execution(...)
```

Documentation on seeding Moto can be found here: http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/configuration/recorder/index.html#deterministic-identifiers
(It only talks about seeding Moto in the context of recording/replaying requests, but the functionality can be used on it's own.)